# Vue - Translation in single file component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-i18n

I'm using `vue-i18n` for my translations and it works great! But when I'm using the `this.$t()` function inside the `data` function of a single file component the translation is not working.

```
 <template>
  <VFooter
      app
      height="auto"
      color="secondary">
    <VLayout
        justify-center
        row
        wrap>
      <VBtn
          v-for="link in links"
          :key="link.name"
          :to="{ name: link.name }"
          flat
          round
          active-class>
        {{ link.label }}
      </VBtn>
      <VFlex
          py-3
          text-xs-center
          xs12>
        &copy;{{ currentYear }} — <strong>{{ $t('site_name') }}</strong>
      </VFlex>
    </VLayout>
  </VFooter>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'TheSiteFooter',
    data() {
      return {
        links: [
          { name: 'what-is-pinshop', label: this.$t('footer.what_is_pinshop') },
          { name: 'contact-us', label: this.$t('footer.contact_us') },
          { name: 'cookie-policy', label: this.$t('footer.cookie_policy') },
          { name: 'privacy-policy', label: this.$t('footer.privacy_policy') },
          { name: 'terms-and-conditions', label: this.$t('footer.terms_and_conditions') },
        ],
      };
    },
    computed: {
      currentYear() {
        return new Date().getFullYear();
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

But, if I instead change `data` with only the key of translation and then in my template use e.g `{{ $t('footer.what_is_pinshop') }}` the translation loaded is correct. Why does this happen? I'm using the `beforeEnter` router guard to change the translation. I have followed [this example](https://github.com/dobromir-hristov/vue-i18n-starter).

**UPDATE**

If I put `links` as a computed property the translation works. So why it does not happen only in `data` property? I also tried with `this.$i18n.t()`, but nothing

Answer (score 1):

This is, because of the vue lifecycle. Push your `link` data into the array by using the `created` hook. Keep you `data`(model) clean and do not call functions in it. You call this up before all events and reactivity mechanisms have ever been registered.

lifecycle: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

if you're interested how it works: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/tree/dev/src

**UPDATE**
I just showered and thought again about it. In depth this is because of the reactivity mechanism. You initialize your data with a function and vue cannot detect if the returned value has changed. See how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty in vue 3 this is replaced by https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: ok, now it's more clear. I figured out that a possible solution could be to add instead of the string already translated. only the key of my translation and in my template I could use `{{ $t(link.label) }}`. So the array of `links` will be: `[{name: 'what-is-pinshop', label: 'footer.what_is_pinshop'}]`

Comment: I have to remove my example, because it was wrong. But the rest is correct. Yeah you can do this or use the i18n directive: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/directive.html#custom-directive-localization